# what is the name of the "title label" in google map top left corner

Tags: google-maps

I'm using `Google Map v3`.

Take a look at the example : https://embed-dot-more-than-a-map.appspot.com/demos/visualization/earthquakes

I need to do something as the "title label" in the top left corner but I can't find it in the doc. 
Is this a div they add in HTML or something which exist on the doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into the source coude, here you'll find

```
<div id="map-time" class="mtam-title">Sat Sep 01 2012</div>
```

So, this is just a custom div they've added, and its updated with some logic.